# My son applied for UK Visa refused

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, serial-refusals

[image]My son applied for UK visa to participate in Student Formula sponsored by his Institute IIT Bombay which is top 1 Institute in India.He is studying 2nd yr, 3 more yrs to complete the course.
I am farmer , having 30 acres of land . Getting about 20 lakhs rupees Indian currency. income .As agriculture income is tax exempted.It is not reflected anywhere.About 16 lakh Indian currency is there in bank account.What documents to be kept ready for next year event participation?

Comment: "*Lakh*" is not generally understood outside of India.

Comment: so your son serially applied for visa on being denied without providing any data to improve his chances and you're wondering why he was denied again?